# Exif-read-data, looping thru arrays/section - getting result

Tags: php, function, foreach, exif

I'm trying to extract the exif information from an image with this foreach-loop and printing out for example the camera maker:

```
function readoutexifinfo($cur_image){
    $exif = exif_read_data($cur_image, 0, true);
    foreach ($exif as $key => $section) {   // $key IFD0; COMPUTED, ANY TAG, EXIF etc.
        foreach ($section as $name => $val) {
            if($key == "ANY_TAG"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
            if($key == "FILE"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
            if($key == "COMPUTED"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
            if($key == "IFD0"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
            if($key == "EXIF"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
            if($key == "INTEROP"){
                echo $key.':'.$name.': '.$val."<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "Camera maker: ".$exif['IFD0']['make'];
}
```

The variabel $cur_image is predefined with an .jpg image.
When i run this:

```
readoutexifinfo($cur_image);
```

I get this error message:

> **Notice:** Undefined index: make

So my question is how can I get elements from ex. IFDO ['camera']['make'] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that line is giving you that error, then the element `$exif['IFD0']['make']` simply does not exist. Did you mean `$exif['IFD0']['camera']['make']` ?

Comment: Thank you for leading me in the right direction ! :) When i tried $exif['IFD0']['camera']['make'] the problem jumped to "camera", but with a little bit of trial and error the solution was:                                              echo "Camera maker: ".$exif['IFD0']['Make'];